# Android: Upload to Google does not work because "com.example" exists somewhere

Tags: android

The question is in the title. My upload to Google does not work because "com.example" package appears somewhere but I renamed all the packages, so I do not know what is going on. See attached screenshots.

[image: Playstore error]

[image: My package and code]

Comment: Change it in your Gradle & android manifest too.

Comment: Thanks, In Gradle it was not changed! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have made an answer so it can be marked as correct :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it in your gradle too, search it for com.example and replace it with your new string.

Good luck!